# possible to turn content thats scrolling to a fixed position at a current position on page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to find away to make a one page site,

the first view of site will be fixed. each layer that scrolls in from bottom becomes fixed when it take full position of the viewport then the next frame slide in while scrolling.

How can I do this?

Is it possible with just css? If not what jquery plugin can I use to do this?

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you're looking for, can you provide an example site with similar behaviour or an attempt you've made?

Comment: ok www.bp-fitness.com see how the first thing you see is a fixed background. I want to create something like that, and when the fixed background is completely covered I want the area covering it to become fixed.. and so on so it looks as if each view page that comes up is being laid over the previous one.

Comment: this is almost what im looking for. http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_reveal/ but i want the turtles to scroll on top of the red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something Like this

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    color:white;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

### **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/35JEv/1/)**

Comment: no, im sorry I am trying to explain my vision here. imagine you have 5 pages. all on one page. page one is fixed. when page to strolls up over it and becomes the view of the whole page it becomes fixed and then page three starts scrolling up over it. I basically want to find a way to change a page to fixed once it covers the whole viewport